# PostgreSQL -- is it possible to use named window in query's ORDER BY clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, window-functions

I'm trying to do something along the lines of

```sql
SELECT id, sum(weight) OVER w
FROM foo
-- Use random() to break ties
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY weight DESC, random())
ORDER BY w
LIMIT 1;
```

but it errors out with

```
ERROR:  column "w" does not exist
LINE 5: ORDER BY w
```

I can of course rewrite it as

```sql
SELECT id, sum(weight) OVER w
FROM foo
-- Use random() to break ties
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY weight DESC, random())
ORDER BY weight DESC, random()
LIMIT 1;
```

But in addition to shortening the query (the full query I'm working on is much more complicated and has several window functions over `w`), I want to capture the same `random()` ordering that was used to calculate `sum(weight)`, rather than have PostgreSQL generate a different, random tie-breaker.

Here's [a DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4koTJCoxAW4MqcrXu1fRhY/1) demonstrating the kind of data set I'm working on. I want to ensure that the second column in the query output will always be monotonically increasing. Is it guaranteed to do so, or does it just happen to do so in this simple synthetic example? My real query has a lot of lateral joins which are in fact designed to thwart the optimiser's lifting constants out of it, so I'm not sure it will always hold.

***Edit**: as @laurenz-albe points out, this is not directly possible. However, in my specific case, I realised that I already have a value that can be directly sorted on, in `sum(weight)`, [like in this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4koTJCoxAW4MqcrXu1fRhY/2).*

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this from Postgres without using dynamic SQL (i.e. writing code to generate your SQL statement).  But, why do you need this?  I think explicitly rewriting the `ORDER BY` clause is actually much clearer to read and maintain.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Because I'm trying to get the same ordering that was used to calculate the `sum(weight)`. If I type it out twice, I'm expecting PostgreSQL to generate two different orderings with random tie-breaking. Because I know for a fact I have a large number of ties, getting the same order is important.

Comment: Adding sample data to explain the logic here might be helpful.  At least, someone can probably give you a workaround for what you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: good point, done.

Comment: But also, I realised I can order by `sum(weight)` and use that as a proxy for the order that was generated, so I guess my specific problem can be solved easily and concisely.

Comment: Yeah...I more or less also saw this, it makes no sense to be ordering by the `SUM` over the entire table anyway.  So Gordon's answer is technically correct then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot take the shortcut of using the window name in the `ORDER BY` clause. You will have to repeat the expressions there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `order by` -- `w` is a window frame not a column.  Presumably, you want something like:

```
SELECT id, sum(weight) OVER w
FROM foo
-- Use random() to break ties
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY weight DESC, random())
ORDER BY 2
LIMIT 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3ba275d207860ca710706540dc5ad682) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Actually, I think the OP wants `ORDER BY weight DESC, random()`, rather than what your answer says.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: you are correct, let me edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @mathrick . . . :This answers the question you have asked here.  I would suggest that you ask a new question, if you have a question about something other than the syntax error in this question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: It's not a syntax error, it's telling me that `w` is not a column in `foo` (which it isn't). I asked a question which I thought was clear, I now know it wasn't as clear as I originally thought, so I disambiguated it, but it's still the question I want answered. I don't see the point in asking another question which is gonna be identical to what I just posted but with an extra code block at the end.